# ActiveMQ: Cron expression for last day of the every month

Tags: cron, activemq-classic

Since ,I have use this cron expression "0 0 L * *" for creating scheduled job in activeMQ. but it throws an exception illustrating "when trying to send:For input string: "L"".
Please suggest any other way to scheduled job for every Month in ActiveMQ.

I'm using ActiveMq version 5.8.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `0 0 0 L * ?` ?

Comment: use 0 0 L * * would help you.

Comment: hey Rahul i have  use that expression but the Exception is  same.

Answer (score 1):

The Cron parser in ActiveMQ is fairly limited in comparison to a real CronTab implementation.  I think the error indicates that support for the special characters such as 'L' is not there.

You can always download the code and give it a once over and see if you can improve it with a pull request.